# Error Param.cc inf value

Tags: gazebo-6, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am trying to spawn a robot made in URDF in Gazebo 6 but I have  the following problem.

At the beginning the robot seems ok but after a few seconds all the links seems to be placed at the origin of the world and I have the following message :

> Error [Param.cc:462] Unable to set value [-inf -inf -inf 1.44116 -0.993549 1.9651] for key[pose]

Is there a problem with the way I use to set link's positions of my robot ?

I am using origin tag in my joints to place the several links of the robots :

```
<joint name="body_arch_fixed" type="revolute">
    <parent link="body"/>
    <child link="arch"/>
    <origin xyz="0.11105 0 1.4498" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit upper="0" lower="0" effort="10" velocity="10"/>
</joint>
```

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12291/error-param.cc-inf-value/) by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 284 on 2016-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Problem solved : PID in controller_manager had too important values

---

Originally posted by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) with karma: 284 on 2016-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dpak.shimpo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4802/dpak.shimpo/) on 2018-04-09**:
Hello Brosseau.F,

Can you please detail the solution? Is there any rule to set PID